# leaps: issues with factor variables

Tags: r, regression, tibble

I'm trying to use the forward stepwise selection in order to choose the best predictors for a logistic regression.
This is the structure of my database

```
spec_tbl_df [7,397 x 19] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ X1                     : num [1:7397] 9617 12179 9905 5745 10067 ...
 $ Administrative         : num [1:7397] 5 26 4 3 7 16 4 3 2 0 ...
 $ Administrative_Duration: num [1:7397] 408 1562 58 103 165 ...
 $ Informational          : num [1:7397] 2 9 2 0 1 3 4 5 0 0 ...
 $ Informational_Duration : num [1:7397] 47.5 503.7 28.5 0 28.5 ...
 $ ProductRelated         : num [1:7397] 54 183 82 25 115 86 75 23 27 33 ...
 $ ProductRelated_Duration: num [1:7397] 1547 9676 4729 1109 3428 ...
 $ BounceRates            : num [1:7397] 0 0.0111 0 0 0 ...
 $ ExitRates              : num [1:7397] 0.01733 0.0142 0.01454 0.00167 0.01629 ...
 $ PageValues             : num [1:7397] 0 19.57 9.06 61.3 4.97 ...
 $ SpecialDay             : num [1:7397] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Month                  : Factor w/ 10 levels "Aug","Dec","Feb",..: 8 8 8 1 8 4 8 7 8 8 ...
 $ OperatingSystems       : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 4 8 2 ...
 $ Browser                : Factor w/ 13 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 5 ...
 $ Region                 : Factor w/ 9 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 2 1 6 4 8 1 1 7 3 ...
 $ TrafficType            : Factor w/ 19 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 12 2 5 10 4 2 4 2 1 ...
 $ VisitorType            : Factor w/ 3 levels "New_Visitor",..: 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 1 3 ...
 $ Weekend                : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Revenue                : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

The target variable to predict is Revenue.

The first time I run the function it showed up the months inside the variable "Month" as they were predictors. Same for the variable "Visitor Type" and for "Weekend", but not for "Region" (so I assume you can actually use factor variables with leaps). Below the output

```
fwd.regfit=regsubsets(Revenue~. ,shoppers_train, method = "forward", nvmax = 20)
summary.fwd.regfit=summary(fwd.regfit)
summary.fwd.regfit

1 subsets of each size up to 20
Selection Algorithm: forward
          X1  Administrative Administrative_Duration Informational Informational_Duration ProductRelated ProductRelated_Duration
1  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            " "                    
2  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            " "                    
3  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            " "                    
4  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
5  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
6  ( 1 )  " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
7  ( 1 )  " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
8  ( 1 )  " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
9  ( 1 )  " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
10  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
11  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
12  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
13  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
14  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     "*"           " "                    " "            "*"                    
15  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     "*"           " "                    " "            "*"                    
16  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     "*"           " "                    " "            "*"                    
17  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     "*"           " "                    " "            "*"                    
18  ( 1 ) "*" "*"            " "                     "*"           " "                    " "            "*"                    
19  ( 1 ) "*" "*"            " "                     "*"           " "                    " "            "*"                    
20  ( 1 ) "*" "*"            " "                     "*"           " "                    " "            "*"                    
          BounceRates ExitRates PageValues SpecialDay MonthDec MonthFeb MonthJul MonthJune MonthMar MonthMay MonthNov MonthOct
1  ( 1 )  " "         " "       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      " "      " "     
2  ( 1 )  " "         " "       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
3  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
4  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
5  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
6  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
7  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
8  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
9  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
10  ( 1 ) " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
11  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
12  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
13  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      "*"     
14  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      "*"     
15  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      "*"     
16  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        "*"        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      "*"     
17  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        "*"        "*"      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      "*"     
18  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        "*"        "*"      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      "*"     
19  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        "*"        "*"      " "      "*"      " "       " "      "*"      "*"      "*"     
20  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        "*"        "*"      " "      "*"      "*"       " "      "*"      "*"      "*"     
          MonthSep OperatingSystems Browser Region TrafficType VisitorTypeOther VisitorTypeReturning_Visitor WeekendTRUE
1  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              " "                          " "        
2  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              " "                          " "        
3  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              " "                          " "        
4  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              " "                          " "        
5  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              "*"                          " "        
6  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              "*"                          " "        
7  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              "*"                          " "        
8  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
9  ( 1 )  " "      "*"              " "     " "    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
10  ( 1 ) " "      "*"              "*"     " "    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
11  ( 1 ) " "      "*"              "*"     " "    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
12  ( 1 ) " "      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
13  ( 1 ) " "      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
14  ( 1 ) " "      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
15  ( 1 ) "*"      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
16  ( 1 ) "*"      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
17  ( 1 ) "*"      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
18  ( 1 ) "*"      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
19  ( 1 ) "*"      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
20  ( 1 ) "*"      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"
```

After some research online I found a possible solution which consists on using the function "ungroup" on my tiddle database. Of course it was a terrible idea and I realized that later when I run again the function. Now every level of my factor variables shows up as a separated predictor (as it happened for the variable month).

How can I fixt it ? I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: To start, let's start by saying that you should include the data (or part of it) and the code you're using in the question. Without it, it's hard to help you. Second, you write that you want to apply logistic regression and at the same time you want to predict revenue. It is unlikely to succeed. Logistic regression is used when the dependent variable (your income) is a variable that only takes two values. Read it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression

Comment: See also this very interesting and informative example.
https://www.guru99.com/r-generalized-linear-model.html

Comment: Hi Marek! Thanks for your reply. How should I include the data ? Do you prefer a summary or a screenshot of the whole matrix ?
The variable Revenue (as you can see in the structure of my databse) is a factorial variable that can only take values TRUE or FALSE, so it is totally compatible with the logistic regression. I just added the code I used to perfom the forward stepwise selection. Hope you can help me.